# How to get current page index in fragment of viewpager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-gridview

My app is an icon view like app drawer

Each page has 12 icons, if more than 12 icons, other icons will display in next page.

I use viewpager and gridview to implement this interface, Each fragment of viewpager has a gridview to display items.

In FragmentActivity, I can get the current page index by adding OnPageChangeListener to viewpager.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

But I cannot get the index in fragment

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";

    public static final MyFragment newInstance(String message)
    {
        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
        bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        f.setArguments(bdl);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String message = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

        //suppose the list has 15 items now
        ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(6);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(8);
        list.add(9);
        list.add(10);
        list.add(11);
        list.add(12);
        list.add(13);
        list.add(14);
        list.add(15);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        int currentIndex=??? //how to get index?

        if(currentIndex==0){
            gridview.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(list.subList(0,12));
        } else if (currentIndex==1) {
            gridview.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(list.subList(12,15));
        }

        return v;
    }


}
```

The fragment in different page should display different sub list of items, how get index in fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method named `getItem(int position)` you will have to override when you create your FragmentPagerAdapter. You can pass the index there.

Since you have this:

`public static final MyFragment newInstance(String message)
    {
        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
        bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        f.setArguments(bdl);
        return f;
    }`

You can put your index in your bdl and get it later in your onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

You should get reference to viewPager in your fragment and just read it.

viewPager.getCurrentItem()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem%28%29